# Excel 2010/2013 VBA import Current Balance from Website

Tags: html, excel, vba, import

I'm very new to VBA, and much less so to HTML.  What I'm trying to do is be able to click a button and retrieve the current balance from a website.  Ideally, I'd like to click one button and have it loop through all of the credit card links and pull the current balance, but I will be happy if I can just get it to work for one site.  I've scoured the web for the past few days and was able to cobble together what I have below.  Please excuse some of the commented out sections as I was going by trial and error.  Any help, and in terms a five year old could understand, would be greatly appreciated.

So, where did I go wrong?  Thank you!!

By the way, I've switched out both of these following lines and associated "dims" with the same result.  'Object not supported by this property or method.'

> ```
> With ieDoc
>  .getElementsByClassName("amount").innerText
> End With
>
> '    dd = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("amount").innerText
> ```

```
 Sub CurrentBalance()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Dim dd As Variant 'IHTMLElementCollection
    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.Navigate "https://www.discovercard.com"

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set ieDoc = IE.document

    With ieDoc
     .getElementsByClassName("amount").innerText
    End With

'    dd = IE.document.getElementByClassName("amount")

    Range("B2").Value = ieDoc


' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

My apologies as I should add the HTML portion:

```
href="/cardmembersvcs/personalprofile/pp/MyProfilePage?ICMPGN=ACHOME_ACCTSUMM_PROFILE_TXT" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>
                    <!-- WT blank content -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-balances">
            <ul>
                <li>Current Balance</li>
                <li class="amount">$910.74</li>
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer is installed on the machine where the macro runs? IE9 was the first version of IE to support `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I may be wrong, but `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, no? So, must be smth like `.getElementsByClassName("amount")[0].innerText` (or in the loop with `.getElementsByClassName("amount")[nthElement].innerText`)... Sorry, I'm not very familiar with VB...

Comment: @ankzhet `getElementsByClassName` returns an IHTMLElementCollection so the syntax is slightly different - `.getElementsByClassName("amount")(0).innerText` - but your general point is entirely correct

Comment: Hi ... thank you  both.  I'm using IE 11.  I've gotten a bit closer with the following:

dd = IE.document.getElementById("amount")

but not sure how to pass that to B2.  I get no error.  Just nothing.

Comment: If you using `getElementById` then your's `html` should look like `<li id="amount">$910.74</li>`

Comment: `Range("B2").Value = dd` should work as long as the `getElementById` part actually worked

Comment: Well, that's going to be a variable.  It's not always going to be that amount.  I'm trying to pull whatever amount is there when I run the code.  So, should I leave the dollar amount blank?  I've been working on this for several days and I have no clue what I'm doing.  I've tried everything I can think of.  The code I tried above is the only thing that didn't produce an error, but it didn't produce anything else, either.

Comment: No one has anything?  Is this just something that's not possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute this into your current code (keeping everything before the "Set ieDoc" line the same):

```
Set ieDoc = IE.document

With ieDoc
    Set dd = .getElementsByClassName("amount")

    Range("B2").Value = dd(0).InnerText
End With

' Clean up
IE.Quit
Set ieDoc = Nothing
Set IE = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

This uses "getElementsByClassName" because the HTML given doesn't have any element with an ID of "amount". This should return a collection from which we take the first item (item 0) and then copy its innerText to cell B2.

What seems to be missing though is any form of login or navigation on the site you're trying to access. This code will only work if the data you're trying to download is visible on the https://www.discovercard.com page without needing you to login

Comment: Hi barrowc,

I get a with variable not set at the range("B2").value = dd(0).InnerText

This is pretty tough stuff, this code business.  LOL

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question, I have an app that logs me into websites, so that shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: I'm getting an "Object variable or with variable not set" at the "range("B2").value = dd(0).innertext" line.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: After the `Set dd = .getElementsByClassName("amount")` line, add this line to show how many elements were retrieved: `MsgBox "Number of elements found = " & dd.length` Report back how many elements were found

Comment: I get: "Number of elements found = 0"

Comment: ... then the HTML of the page you are examining doesn't have any elements with class="amount". After the `Set ieDoc = IE.document` line, add this new line: `MsgBox IE.LocationURL`. Check that the URL which appears in the message box corresponds to the correct webpage that you are trying to examine